# Load model with Condition deleted at null laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**This Is My model**

```
  public function topic()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Topic::class);
    }
    public function flashCard()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(FlashCard::class);
    }
    public function exerciseGroup()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ExerciseGroup::class);
    }
}
```

**This is My code in controller**

```
 $data= ChapterContent::with(['exerciseGroup','topic','flashCard'])->where('chapter_id','=',$chapter_id)->get();
```

This will return all my contents with exerciseGroup,topic and flashCards

But the Problem is my exerciseGroup,topic and flashCards using softdelets so It will return null on my
data.(which means not cascading in chapter_contents table).. How can i return only the available topics,exerciseGroups and flashCards not deleted ones..??

Answer (score 0):

just use `has` or `whereHas`, see documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

```
  $data= ChapterContent::with(['exerciseGroup','topic','flashCard'])
         ->has('exerciseGroup')
         ->has('topic')
         ->has('flashCard')
         ->where('chapter_id','=',$chapter_id)
         ->get();
```

Comment: Not it returns [] empty array

Comment: it's mean no data which has these relations, are you sure you have the not deleted one on these 3 tables? if 1 table doesn't have it make empty result, as all relation is required, otherwise you can use `orHas` method too

Comment: consider a situation my contents table has topic id 1 and topic id  1 is softdeleted.. when i call this nested eager loading returns topic id 1 and topics as null .. how can i avoid this?

Comment: like i only want to return the data which are not soft deleted..

Comment: just use `->has('topic')`, if return empty result it's mean you don't have ChapterContent which has topic that not soft deleted. try to create ChapterContent and its topic first.